# Sort files from a local directory

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have direct link to my local directory files(PDF files) and I want it to be sorted by datemodified or descending when i open it from the interface.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

### Specsheets

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <input id="specsheets" class="form-control" />
    </div>

<div class="row row-centered">
    <div class="col-md-4" >
        <a href='\alpha\specsheets' class='btn btn-warning btn-block btn-menu-btn' target="_blank"><i class='fa fa-file-text' aria-hidden='true' target="_blank"></i>Specbuild</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? What does the view code have to do with anything here?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Alex, I have this internal system and in this system/website i have button that show a local directory file which is .pdf files. And my concern is how can I sort this pdf files with the newest file on top top. 
Thank you and I hope you understand.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. The above "code" isn't relevant or is missing pieces to provide "the whole picture". Show us the relevant code that you have written to accomplish your task thus far. If this is it, please try more on your own, this isn't a code writing service.